# Google Map Street View Not Working - grayed out

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

[www.bchomescondos.ca/properties/?city=Burnaby&id=261618646](http://www.bchomescondos.ca/properties/?city=Burnaby&id=261618646)

[www.bchomescondos.ca/properties/?city=Burnaby&id=261711367](http://www.bchomescondos.ca/properties/?city=Burnaby&id=261711367)

These are just the few of the sample pages where the problem is arising. I am not too proficient with the Google Map API, but still tried to incorporate on my website. 
I have added three tabs- one showing the road map, another the street view and the third is the walkscore. While the road map and walk-score is working fine, the street view isn't. 
But one strange thing I have noticed is if the page is resized (just for any weird reason) the street view map appears. 
I would be very much obliged if anyone helps me with this problem.

**The Script**

http://pastebin.com/zQTCxez2

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.19&sensor=true_or_false"></script>

<script>
var geocoder;
var ws_wsid = 'afca921c9778417e8dc16a8236d1f079';
var ws_address = "<?php echo $row['address']; ?>,<?php echo $row['city']; ?>";
var ws_width = '100%';
var ws_height = '400';
var ws_layout = 'vertical';
var ws_commute = 'true';
var ws_transit_score = 'true';
var ws_map_modules = 'all';
var address = "<?php echo $row['address']; ?>,<?php echo $row['city']; ?>";

function initialize() {
    var fenway = new google.maps.LatLng( <? php echo $row['latitude']; ?> , <? php echo $row['longtitude']; ?> )
    var mapOptions = {
        center: fenway,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
    var contentString = '<a class="fancybox-inline" href="#request_form_pop">Request of showing this property</a>';
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: fenway,
        map: map,
        title: ''

    });


    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {});

    var panoramaOptions = {
        position: fenway,
        pov: {
            heading: 34,
            pitch: 10
        }
    };
    panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'), panoramaOptions);
    map.setStreetView(panorama);

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

**The HTML**

http://pastebin.com/fgDRR0MN

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="one columns"></div>

        <section class="ten columns tabs" style="margin: 20px 0;">         
            <ul class="tab-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Google Map</a></li>
                <li> <a href="#">Street View</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Walk Score</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content active">
                <div id="map-canvas" style="height: 400px; border: 0.5px solid #000;">
                </div>
            </div>
           <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="pano" style="height: 400px; border: 0.5px solid #000;"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="ws-walkscore-tile" style="height: 400px; border: 0.5px solid #000;"></div>
            </div>
            <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.walkscore.com/tile/show-walkscore-tile.php'></script>            
        </section>

        <div class="one columns"></div>
</div>
```

I just wanted to show the street view when that particular tab is clicked.

**CSS Files**

[http://www.bchomescondos.ca/wp-content/themes/dgdon/css/gumby.css]
[http://www.bchomescondos.ca/wp-content/themes/dgdon/css/style.css]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Alfonso. Actually, since this is my first post on stackoverflow I wasn't sure how to post a code.

**Regarding the code not working- Yes the code will not work as it is because the latitude and longitude is coming from database. In that place you can add any latitude and longitude value. 

** Tip:- Viewing the source code from the above two pages can help.

Comment: `&sensor=true_or_false` - firstly `true_or_false` isn't a valid value for this parameter. Secondly, you don't need to specify the sensor parameter any more anyway, just remove it.

Comment: there's some additional CSS / JS controlling the showing/hiding of the tabs, right?  Can you add that to your question.  I've found in the past with StreetView that I had to make the div visible initially to load it in, then hide it immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the reply duncan.
Actually I haven't add any extra CSS/JS to handle the showing or hiding the  tabs. I have simple used Gumby(responsive framework) to create those tabs. The two CSS is gumby.css and style.css. I will add the links to those css on the main post.

Comment: Can you make the pano tab active initially, so the streetview loads, then use JS to hide it once it's loaded in?

Comment: Fabulous duncan, looks like we are very close to the solution. I simply changed the HTML a bit and made streetview (pano) as the active tab instead of the map-canvas. And boom it appeared perfectly. But now when I switched to the map-canvas tab it looked distorted. So, now I have to find a way to load the tabs same time and hide one initially. I don't have any knowledge in javascript can you help me with that little code?

Comment: So at the end of your initialize function you probably want to do something like `document.getElementById('map-canvas').style.display = 'none';` or if you  use jQuery, just `$('#map-canvas').hide();`

Comment: If I add display:none it will never show. How to make it visible again then?

Comment: well I don't know how Gumby works, but I'd have a JS function triggered when you click on the tabs that then does `document.getElementById('map-canvas').style.display = 'block';`

Answer (score 0):

So, it can be deduced that there is no problem with the map api and it's script. The problem lies with how the CSS tabs are handled. 
Thanks duncan for your help. I would open a new question regarding solving this CSS and JS problem.